# Restrict Access Modifier of Form Class Properties in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, properties, access-modifiers

I created a **DLL class** that inherited **Windows.FORM** , I want to Restrict its **properties** **Access Modifier** like Size(width-height) & FormBorderStyle to **Private**

so unreachable in another Assembly. what should i do and what is relevant to it?
use abstract class maybe? thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Don't do it.

`access modifiers` are meant to guide developers. They, in no way, offer any protection against usage.

A developer which want to access them, is able to, even if they are private and messing with the frameworks defaults can lead to serious issues.

---

#### Alternatively...

If your form is a fully stand alone functionality or feature, then make a wrapper around the form.

For example:

```
//the wrapper
public class PropertyPages : IPropertyPages
{
     //your wrapped form...
     private YourForm _propertyForm = new YourForm(); 

     //a public show, but the form itself remain inaccessible.
     public void Show()
     {
         _propertyForm.Show();
     }
}
```